# How to add value on button click function?

Tags: unity-game-engine

In **Unity**  I have the following code:

```
public Button[] SearchPlayers;

void Start() 
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
       // SearchPlayers[i].onClick.AddListener(Click(i));//here error
       SearchPlayers[i].onClick.AddListener(Click);//not error
    }
}

void Click(int i)
{
   print(i+":button was clicked")
}
```

The problem is if you see my code there is an integer **`i`**. So that value gives an error.How can I solve this error?

Comment: Can you specify your question? And give us more information about the context? What is SearchPlayers?

Comment: SearchPlayers is button of Arrays

Comment: And what do you get as an output now? And what value do you want to add where?

Comment: What problem??? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The problem is if you see my code there is an integer i. So that value gives an error.How can I solve this error?

Comment: That is because you only add the function and not call it. The call happens when you press the button. And besides that I am pretty sure that a button cannot give a function a parameter when he calls it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the context. Calling Click(i) returns void. AddListener does not accept void.

You could solve this problem by creating an appropriate context with which to provide the argument.

```
public Button[] SearchPlayers;

void Start() 
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        //Cache the value
        int index = i;

        SearchPlayers[i].onClick.AddListener(() => Click(index));
    }
}

void Click(int i)
{
   print(i+":button was clicked")
}
```

Comment: Thank you !! You're the perfect

Comment: Not a problem !